# Screen flickering on Ubuntu 20.04 - HP Spectre X360 with Intel Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]

Tags: 20.04, graphics, hp, intel, flicker

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on my HP Spectre X360 with Intel Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] and I am having flickering graphics.

Unlike similar entries that have been reported, my flickering is discontinuous. It sometimes happens showing grey flickering boxes 5-6 times in a minute, and sometimes it does not happen for 2-3 minutes. Overall, it annoys me quite a lot.

I have tried decreasing the refresh rate from 60Hz to lower options, but that didn't work. Updating the drivers or purging Intel graphics didn't work either. I also tried a couple of stuff I saw online regarding `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`.

I do not have this issue on Windows, therefore it must be Ubuntu-related.

When I set `nomodeset` on GRUB and update it, flickering disappears, but at the cost of my brightness adjuster and Night Light. As not being able to adjust the brightness is equally bad, I'm only using it as a temporary solution.

Here are the details of my graphics card:

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Please help me, my hands are tied at this point!

Comment: Did you not notice the first line in your question re details? Here are the details of my graphic card: *-display UNCLAIMED What kernel are you running?

Comment: @David 5.11.0-36-generic

Comment: There are newer kernels that may fix the problem.

Comment: @David unfortunately no, I upgraded it to 5.14.8-051408-generic
The issue persists

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar flicker with kernel 5.15-0.33 and went back to 5.13.0-48 and the flickering stopped. I have that same graphics running Linux Mint which uses the Ubuntu repositories. I did not notice the flickering before 5.15 (not sure if I ever used 5.11, but I know my install of Mint started with 5.4 and there have been many kernel upgrades along the way.) Hopefully you have already solved this problem.